# Jump to position in .Rnw file in PDF produced by knitr

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, sweave, rnw

I'm using knitr to convert .Rnw files to .pdf files. I can use Skim to jump from a position in the .pdf file to the .tex file produced by knitr.

How can I jump from a position in the .pdf file to the .Rnw?

Answer (score 1):

Check out SyncTeX. For example, RStudio's PDF viewer provides a synchronization between the PDF and the underlying Rnw file, see [here](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/overview) or [here](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/pdf_preview).